# Browser-repaint html custom elements v1

Tags: html, shadow-dom

How does a shadow tree or custom element v1 effect browser reflow / repaint?  When causing a reflow / repaint on a sub-element will the whole page reflow / repaint or just the DOM of the shadow tree or custom element v1.  If the custom element "frame" is set to overflow hidden then sub elements would have no effect on the page outside of the "frame".  Of course the same could be said of an ordinary div although that would cause a whole page reflow / repaint.

Comment: flatten shadow dom and custom elements render as any other html element.